# Integrations in real life

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

When we integrate something say work, $\int F\cdot ds$ then we will get work but what exactly is $ds$? How much is $ds$? Is it the Planck length? Are we just pretending there exists some infinitesimals and all the math works out in the end?

Comment: As far as mathematics can describe nature (and as you probably know, it's not very far, as nature doesn't obey mathematical laws), continuum hypothesis works fine for any theoretical research. On the other hand, numerical integration, which is the cornerstone of most applications in real life, explicitly introduces some small but finite lengsh scale $ds \to \Delta s$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going like this can be harmful! Instead, write $$W=\int F ds\implies\frac{dW}{ds}=F$$Now the quantity, $\frac{dW}{ds}$ is the equation slope of tangent lines made in the $W$ v/s $s$ graphs. To be more precise, $ds$ is not alone very small but $dW$ is also considered to be very small. To find exactly how small is $ds$, the statement below might help:$$\mbox{"$ds$ is the nearest real number to $0$ you can think of, but is not equal to zero"}$$

Comment: @DDD4C4U Since you are new here, I warmly suggest to take a few seconds for a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Recall that "The person who asked can mark one answer as accepted."

Answer (score 0):

As small as you can take it! The problem is that when we model a real life phenomena, we can only get a finite number of samples i.e: input-output relations of the function modelling the phenomena. Once we get this, we do something called interpolation where we sort of connect the dots and get the best continuous function which fits through these dots. Now for finding area under this continuous mathematical function, you can do the well known limiting formalisms and use the good ol tools of analysis you are familiar with.